# How can I repeat inner array in a loop?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$locations = array(
    array('Eifel Tower', 48.858278, 2.294254, '#FF7B6F', 'eifel-tower.jpg', 120, 160),
    array('The Louvre', 48.8640411, 2.3360444, '#6BE337', 'the-louvre.jpg', 160, 111), 
    array('Musee d\'Orsay', 48.860181, 2.3249648, '#E6E325', 'musee-dorsay.jpg', 160, 120), 
    array('Jardin du Luxembourg', 48.8469529, 2.337285, '#61A1FF', 'jardin-du-luxembourg.jpg', 160, 106), 
    array('Promenade Plantee', 48.856614, 2.3522219, '#FF61E3', 'promenade-plantee.jpg', 160, 120)
);
```

Can I repeat inner array in a loop, because I need it to repeat from database.
Thanks!

Comment: SO is about - showing your approach, explaining what is not working and providing valid code & expected results. Since it's your first post you're seeing this clarification - but in future that could be your heavily downvoted question instead.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Can you rephrase it please.

Comment: i have to repeat inner array . this one  "array('Eifel Tower', 48.858278, 2.294254, '#FF7B6F', 'eifel-tower.jpg', 120, 160)"

Answer (score 2):

As **Houssni** posted it, but you can do it also like this:

```
foreach ($location as $location_array)
{
    foreach ($location_array as $location_detail)
    {
        var_dump($location_detail);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested `for` loops is the answer:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($locations); $i++)
{
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($locations[$i]); $j++)
    {
        echo $locations[$i][$j];
    }
}
```